# What technology is used for 2d positioning in writing tablets like repaper

Tags: 2d, positioning

I am wondering what is the technology for 2d positioning with note taking tablets like

- repaper - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ivskkyx3UYs
- bamboo - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BqH3FU7VvSQ

I am interested in creating a hand notes simple robot programming for little kids with processing and Arduino. Computer vision can be used for simple commands etc color coded for example, but I want to know how can they achieve getting all coordinates from that ring or so.

Comment: You can search on the google with "usb hid" keyword.

Comment: usb hid is for the interface, i mean about the positioning, magnetic fields? array of hall effect sensors maybe?